# Cannot find/open Bing Maps module Orchard

Tags: .net-4.0, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

When installing the "Bing Maps" module into Orchard 1.6 (source version) the module does not show up under modules in solution explorer.

Other modules are simply found in the root under Modules but for some reason this module is not.

It is located on the following location: `C:\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Bing.Maps`

How come its located here and not showing up in the Solution Explorer (The Orchard.web does not show modules in solution explorer)?

For installation i just went to admin dashboard --> gallery and install.

*I need to edit this module because its having troubles with my regional settings, but i do not like editing files i cannot open in solution explorer (when opening through file/open file many lines are marked in red).*

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules are always physically located on the filesystem under the path e.g. `C:\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\SomeModule` When you install a module, the files are copied to this folder.

The root `Modules` folder that you refer to is a solution folder used in visual studio to organise projects within the solution explorer. Projects can be moved to these virtual folders without affecting their location on the file system. To add your new module to this folder in Visual Studio solution explorer, right click the `Modules` solution folder and select Add => Existing project and select the project file for your new module.

Comment: What if i cannot open the project file? Using visual studio 2012 express (does not work with 2010 either) but i'm unable to open the Bing Maps Module (Unsuporrted error, this version of VS does not have the following project types installed...).

Comment: I looks like this is an older module that has not been upgraded to work with the latest version of Orchard. The project has a project type of MVC2 which will not be recognised unless it is installed on your machine. You can either contact the module developer to see if they can release an upgrade, or you can edit the project file (xml) and replace one of the ProjectTypeGuid entries from F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325 (old MVC2) to E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47 (MVC4). You will then need to open in VS, it will automatically upgrade and you can test it.

Comment: Thanks for the exellent answer damoclarke. Got it finally working (module import in project and the module itself). Had to change the version and the javascript function to make this module work combined with updating the web.configs (intellisense).